# 64 bit dll module doesn't match file

Tags: c++, assembly, module, opcodes

My x64 bit dx11 process loads dxgi.dll and claims to be using the one from C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll.

However, whenever I inspect it in ram, the opcodes don't match up at all as if its loading a different version of the dll.

How can I find the real location/module that it is using?

Answer (score 1):

Windows maps the `system32` folder to a different real folder depending on if the executable is 32 bit or 64 bit.  Under a 32 bit process, this will map to `SysWOW64`, which contains the 32 bit binaries.  A 64 bit process will get the 64 bit binaries in `system32`.  A 32 bit process can see the 64 bit binaries by using the `sysnative` folder, which will map to `system32`.

Comment: Its loading/redirecting the module from C:\Windows\winsxs